# What does the public key encryption provide?

Tags: encryption, certificate, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

This is about a test I did, but I'm asking because I'd like to understand these concepts, I am a little confused about them.

```
Maria encrypts her document with her private key.
Maria sends the document to John
John decrypt the received document using Maria's public key.
```

I'd like to know whether this process provides:

```
1) authenticity
2) integrity
3) non-repudiation
4) confidentiality.
```

I would also like to know which of these 4 items are provided by certificates, and by digital-signature.

Thanks!

Comment: With a few more details we might say yes to #1, #2, and #3. Definitely no to #4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Authenticity You can use public-private key pairs for authentication in there own right, if I'm not mistake ssh does something similar. In fact you can setup servers in such away you do not need to enter a login password based on this principal.
2. Integrity
   I don't believe that the public -private key on its own accounts for this on its own.
3. Non-repudiation
   Cannot be acchieved on its own without have a certifying body saying that the owner of the private key to which you encrypted your public key is the origin you expect it to be. For more
   [click here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-to-achieve-non-repudiation)
4. Confidentiality 
   the way it works is that you have public-private key pairs the 'public' have access to a key which they used to encrypt data but only one person has the private key to decrypt it. Therefore it brings about confidentiality only the intended person can read the data.